Of high importance
Who is the...

...?

The answer is a 4-letter name. Explain your reasoning.
Hint 1:

 For the Arabic text: What's special about it? It could be described as the...  For the wordplay part: The 7-letter word has nothing to do with that number and nothing to do with bananas (although it could be associated with bananas)

Hint 2 (stronger):

 19 is a... (what?)


Since, there are Arabic letters, shall I read it left to right or right to left?

@M.Riyan Start with the Arabic part, then the bananas part. So left to right.

Added some more info. The focus is ofc on the two parts, but just added the numbers/word as instructions.

Should it be (4)(2)(8) for the first part?

@PDT No, as it is

The wordplay part baffles me. I thought it might be rot13("ryrzrag", fvapr ab. avargrra vf cbgnffvhz, juvpu onananf ner snzbhf sbe. Gung qbrfa'g jbex jvgu "Jub vf ...", gubhtu, naq gur ZI ryrzrag unf zber guna sbhe yrggref).

@MOehm It's a good guess, but yeah it has nothing to do with rot13(purzvpny ryrzragf). With the help of the title and the movie-tag I think you can get this since you solved the Arabic part.

@MOehm I also ended up down the dead end of rot13(cbgnffvhz, naq jnf fher jr jrer ybbxvat ng gur flzoby sbe gur Xhjnvgv qvane sbe n ybat gvzr, ohg gur rahzrengvbaf qba'g svg...)

@Stiv: I'm writing an answer right now. (I'm sure I've said that before recently ...) :)

@MOehm Aha, now everything makes sense - so I was actually right with the LHS but just couldn't see its significance, I get it now...

I think I got it, the answer is

 Jack

Because

 He's the 'MVP: Most Valuable Primate' in the 2000 comedy film.
 The Arabic text is KWD - Kuwaiti Dinar which is the 'most valuable' currency in the world.
 19 is a 'prime', and number '8' on the list on primes at that - and 'primate' is a wordplay on that. Extra connection that primates are associated with eating bananas.


Ha! I'm too slow. Well done!

@MOehm Thanks, I noticed your answer was in the same minute. Sorry!

Photo finish... No need to be sorry.

Well done! :) However I chose the number 19 instead of any other P for a reason

Just make a small edit explaining the wordplay in more detail (look at @MOehm 's edit)

@Prim3numbah that's a nice detail, updated

The answer is:

 JACK.

The rebus:

 The Arabic text is the abbreviation of the Kuwaiti dinar, which has the highest excahneg rate per base unit. Therefore it is the MOST VALUABLE CURRENCY.

 The bananas form the eigth prime number, 19, or prime #8, which sounds like PRIMATE. The bananas are stereotypical fare for a primate.

Wrapping it up:

 This gives us "Who is the MOST VALUABLE PRIMATE?" In the film of that title, the primate protagonist is called JACK.


Correct :) But an almost identical answer, just seconds before you, was given so tick goes to @fandango96

That's fine with me.

Your explanation for the 7-letter word works ofc but I chose 19 instead of any other P for a reason

Oh, let me count, it's p₈. Clever. (To be honest, I wasn't too confident about my homophone.)
